# How Do I Pass A Parameter into A Get Request to A Flask Blueprint Python App?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask/blueprint app that works with hard-coded or `all()` GET requests. This is the code in `api.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

from ..extensions import db
from ..models.users import Users

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

@api.route('/user/<name>')
def get_user(email):
    users = Users.query.first()

    return {'users': users.email}
```

The above code works and doing `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/user/anythingHere` in Postman returns:

```
{
    "users": "test@example.com"
}
```

Which is correct and corresponds with my database. But when I modify the code in `api.py` to look like this:

```
from flask import Blueprint

from ..extensions import db
from ..models.users import Users

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

@api.route('/user/<name>')
def get_user(email):
    users = Users.query.filter_by(email='<name>').first()

    return {'users': users.email}
```

And in Postman run `http://127.0.0.1:5000/user/test@example.com` hoping that `test@example.com` will populate `<name>` in `filter_by(email='<name>')`, but obviously this doesn't work as indicated by the fact that I get `TypeError: get_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'` in my terminal and this in Postman:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or
    there is an error in the application.</p>
```

So how do I pass the email parameter from the GET request to the get_user function?

Comment: You're using `name` in your URL path, but then `email` in your function arguments, and then `name` again in your query. Rename it to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `email` into the function as `email` not `<email>` like this:

```
from flask import Blueprint

from ..extensions import db
from ..models.users import Users

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

@api.route('/user/<email>')
def get_user(email):
    users = Users.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

    return {'users': users.email}
```